# QUrl and encoding

Tags: qt

I'm having a problem on mac with Qt 4.8.x

I have a mailto QURL which has a body component that's encoded. Simplifying it:

```
mailto:?subject=Hello&body=Hello%2C%0A%0AYou%20have%20been%20invited
```

My problem is that the **encoding still shows on the mail body** when my default app launches (tried multiple e-mail clients). This works well for Windows, but fails on Mac.

Is there a way for me to have the encoding turn into the encoded characters into readable text in the e-mail client body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QUrl is buggy. There is no way around this bug but to go directly to Cocoa.

```
void MyMacLaunchURLClass::LaunchURL(char * url)
{
    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithCString:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
}
```

That resolved the bug.

Answer (score 2):

Also use [fromPercentEncoding](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qurl.html#fromPercentEncoding) to decode Qurl format in to clear string.

Comment: doesn't work. i have "&" in a url in the email body. it truncates my test when i hit that "&